# CSS last-child with class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/SJyV3/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="tt">tt</div>
    <div class="tt">tt</div>
    <div class="huh">huh</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tt:nth-child(2) {
    color:blue;
}
#parent .tt:last-child {
    color:red;
}
```

Is it possible to select last child element with provided class?

Comment: would you want to select this <div class="tt">tt</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 div.tt:last-child {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Actually selects the last child. However it doesn't select the last instance of a class if it is not the last one in it's parent.

So you have to change your HTML to:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="ttwrppaer">
        <div class="tt">tt</div>
        <div class="tt">tt</div>
        <div class="tt">tt</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hhhd">tt</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJyV3/7/)

Comment: Thats bad, i thought selector is searching in provided class childrens. Seems like it's ignoring provided class and pick all childrens. :(

Comment: Yea i will have to remove last children with another class to some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to select last-child div inside parent (`#parent`) div element. So you need to select it like that.

Try this:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="tt">tt</div>
    <div class="tt">tt</div>
    <div class="huh">huh</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tt:nth-child(2) {
    color:blue;
}
div div:last-of-type {
    color:red;
}
```

[Try this 1](http://jsfiddle.net/SJyV3/11/)

OR

```
.tt:nth-child(2) {
    color:blue;
}
div div:last-child {
    color:red;
}
```

[Try this 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SJyV3/12/)